# Regex to check non-repetition of a set of characters

Tags: regex, set, permutation

Suppose I have the set of characters `[ABC]`. I'm looking for a regex that would match any permutation of the superset except the empty set, i.e.

```
ABC ACB BAC BCA CAB CBA
AB BC AC CB CA BA
A B C
```

The regex should (obviously) *not* match the empty string.

p.s. An alternative way to express the same objective is "match any non-empty string containing each character in the set at most once".

update: The set `[ABC]` is just an example, for the real set may also be bigger. With this question I was hoping to find a "general" solution rather than a particular one for `[ABC]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your answers (especially anubhava's and codaddict's) I was able to find this solution, that I think is pretty elegant because it allows to type the set only once:

```
\b(([ABC])(?!.*\2))+\b
```

the `\b` are needed to match full words; omitting them will also find subwords respecting the required property. To match a full string, you'd obviously do:

```
^(([ABC])(?!.*\2))+$
```

Comment: OK, I just noticed that; **really** elegant take on the subject (tried something similar, but didn't manage to make it work... :-S). Good work! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I believe this can be solved by regular expressions. Use this regex:

```
/^([ABC])(?!\1)([ABC])?(?!\1|\2)[ABC]?$/
```

Let me know if you need an online demo on this.

Comment: @anubhava I suppose the `(?!\1)` means "look forward and make sure match #1 is not there"? I did not know this regex feature existed (though honestly I tried it like `(?!$1)` (pretty much like when replacing). I think I've learnt something new today... :-)

Comment: I also created a demo with lots of test strings: http://www.rubular.com/r/TpkItUFW75

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Yes `(?!\1)` is a **negative look-ahead** which means here that `A or B or C` are not immediately followed by same characters to avoid matching `AA` or `BB` or `CC` cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that regular expressions are good at. You might just want to create a list of permutations instead, and then produce all unique substrings.

something like:

```
def matches(s, characters):
    if len(s) != len(set(s)):
        return False # not unique sequence of characters
    return set(s).issubsetof(set(characters))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
([ABC]?)(?!.*\1)([ABC]?)(?!.*\2)[ABC]?
```

It is just `[ABC]?` repeated 3 times with the added check of the negative lookahead assertion that does not permit duplicate characters.

Note that this would work only if the input set is all unique.

[**See it work**](http://www.rubular.com/r/Xe0mFFie4W)

Answer (score 1):

```
"A((B?C?)|(C?B?))|B((A?C?)|(C?A?))|C((A?B?)|(B?A?))"
```

It is A|B|C and each of them can be followed by an pair of optional values

```
 A(B?C?) matches A, AB,AC and ABC
 A(C?B?) matches A, AC,AB and ACB
```

but not ACAC, AA or ACC. The cases with B or C as first character are equivalent.

For longer Strings, this will get ugly soon. A better approach would be (pseudocode):

```
 string.sort().matches ("^A?B?C?$") && string.length > 0
```

Comment: Looks like the only correct solution to me. In my eyes, this should be the accepted solution. Most of the other solutions (also the accepted solution) still allow ABB, ACC, BAA, BBC, CCA and so on.

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder: Thanks, but I just tested the second solution of CAFxX, and it worked for me, too, while being much smaller.

Comment: Ah, okay... I have misread the answer of CAFxX then. I thought that the second solution was just an alternative for the first solution. And I had only tested the first solution there.

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder: I tested `echo ABA | grep -P '\b(([ABC])(?!.*\2))+\b'` successfully too, but don't know at which program with which settings it is supposed to work. :)

Comment: I know the commands echo, pipe and grep from Linux, it is used to apply the regular expression in the Unix console or Linux console or Mac OS X console and to test it there. It will not work below Windows, unless you install something like Cygwin there.

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder: You can install the Gnu32-tools, which is a collection of very popular unix commands, natively compiled for the windos platform. I don't know whether a x64 version is available, too.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, Cygwin is a popular GNU tool which can perform Unix/Linux commands below Windows. I know that. ;-)

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder: I know Cygwin, which is something different. It is an environment to run linux programs (without recompilation, afaik), while the gnu-utils are compiled as native Windows programs. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :** (UPDATED)

```
A[BC](?![ABC])|B[AC](?![ABC])|C[AB](?![ABC])|[ABC](?![ABC])|(ABC|ACB|BAC|BCA|CAB|CBA)(?![ABC])
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30pa6

Comment: It will match AAA also though (which from the question _may_ not be ok)

Comment: All of the groups are optional, so it will match an empty string

Comment: Also, I used a three character group as an example; the actual set may be bigger.

Comment: @CAFxX - it might help if you mention this in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version:

```
\b(?=[ABC]{1,3})([ABC]{1})(?:(?!\1)([ABC]{1})(?:(?!\1)(?!\2)[ABC]{1})?)?\b
```

Logic:

- `\b`: look for a word boundary
- `(?=[ABC]{1,3})`: lookahead to see if there is a string of length = 3 with values of only A, B, C
- `([ABC]{1})`:  match the first character
  then optionally
- `(?!\1)([ABC]{1})`: check if the next character is not the same as previously matched - if it's not, match it
  and optionally
- `(?!\1)(?!\2)[ABC]{1}`: check if the next character is not the same as previously matched char 1 or 2 - if it's not, match the character

I tested it against this input, so it seems quite reliable:

AABCC BBCC
AB BC AC CB CA BA
A B C
ABC ACB BAC BCA CAB CBA
AAA ABB
AAA BBC
AA

---

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned the character set can be larger I would follow the PS advice in your question and do this the following way:

- introduce `chars` array which will hold each character in the allowed set (split the string into chars)
- get an array of `inputStrings` (split the input string on whitespace or whatever else required)
- for each `string` in `inputStrings`
  {
- check if the `string.length <= inputStrings.length`
- tryMatch each character in the list against the current input and save the number of matches found in a `matches` list
- check if the `matches` list contains any entries and then if all entries == 1 or 0
  }

Answer (score 0):

OK, I must say that I've thought about your question a lot and - since you seem to be wanting something really universal and customiseable (to support as many elements as possible, etc) - this is what I think would make the most optimal solution.

What you want, from a math perspective, is to identify all **permutations of a set of elements without repetition**.

---

#### Step 1 :

Find all permutations of the set, **with** repetition (and store them let's say in an array)

```
[ABC]([ABC]{1,2})?
```

***Sidenote :** let's say you have a set with `n` elements, all you have to do is :*

`[elements]([elements]{1,n-1})?`

---

#### Step 2 :

Filter all permutations with duplicate elements

**Example code in PHP :**

```
<?php

    function strToArray($str)
    {
        $i = 0;

        while (isset($str[$i]))
        {
            $result[$i] = $str[$i];
            $i++;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function noDuplicates($str)
    {
        if (array_unique(strToArray($str))==strToArray($str)) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    $AAA = "AAA";
    $ABC = "ABC";

    if (noDuplicates($AAA)) echo "$AAA : ok"; else echo "$AAA : not ok\n";
    if (noDuplicates($ABC)) echo "$ABC : ok"; else echo "$ABC : not ok\n";

?>
```

**Output :**

```
AAA : not ok
ABC : ok
```