# flex lexical analyzer non-repetition of a set of characters

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

I have the expression

```
[A-E]|[A-E]{3}|[A-E]{4}
```

its made to recognize names of angles `(A,B,C,D,E)` or triangles `(ABC,BCD)` ect or Rectangles `(ABCD,EDCB)` ect

BUT

i want to change the expression so that user CANT input an name with the same letter 2 times, names such AAC or ABAE should not be valid names for a trianlge or rectangle.

I ve seen a regex solution of this type of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332894/regex-to-check-non-repetition-of-a-set-of-characters) but cant see how i can do this on flex and cant find a way to solve this on the patterns of flex manual. Any help/guide would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this in flex is probably with `REJECT`:

```
[A-E]|[A-E]{3}|[A-E]{4}  { for (int i = 0; i < yyleng-1; i++) {
                               if (strchr(yytext+i+1, yytext[i])) {
                                   /* duplicate letter in string */
                                   REJECT; } }
                           return whatever...; }
[A-Z]+                   { return something_else...; }
```

With this, if you have an input like `ABA`, it will match the pattern, but due to the duplicate `A`, it will reject that match and go to match the next-best pattern (`[A-Z]+` in this case) and return something_else...

Also note from the flex documentation:

> 'REJECT' is a particularly expensive feature in terms of scanner performance;
>    if it is used in *any* of the scanner's actions it
>    will slow down *all* of the scanner's matching.  Furthermore,
>    'REJECT' cannot be used with the '-Cf' or '-CF' options

Comment: thanks for the help , i ll try to figure out how i will make it work,  the code with the reject loop should be put on the  definitions,rules or user code part of my lex?

Comment: ok i made it work , btw declare i outside of the loop to avoid the "'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode" Error,

it works for a AAC making it A ,A , C , but not for  CAA...it recognizes it as CAA which is not valid name for triangle...

Answer (score 1):

I have done this

```
names [A-E]{4}|[A-E]{3}|[A-E]
%%

{names} {int i; for (i = 0; i < yyleng-1; i++) {
                               if (strchr(yytext+i+1, *yytext)) {
                                   /* duplicate letter in string */
                                   REJECT; } }
                           return printf( " %s :VALID NAME \n", yytext ); }
[A-Z]+                   { return printf( " %s :INVALID NAME\n", yytext ); }
```

But it works only for duplicated letters that are at the start of 
the expression

ex
ABA :invalid
ABCD:valid
ABCA:invalid

BUT

ABBA :valid (it should be invalid)
ACBC :valid (it should be invalid)

i must find a way to make i work for every situation