# Regex to match (same-length) permutations of AAB

Tags: regex

Hello stackoverflow community!

I want to match all (same-length) string permutations of AAB, so I want to match:

```
AAB
BAA
ABA
```

but not:

```
ABB
AB
AABA
```

I have already found many sources mentioning lookarounds and backreferences at similar questions such as [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101366/regex-to-match-1234-1324-2341-all-permutations-of-1-2-3-4) or [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332894/regex-to-check-non-repetition-of-a-set-of-characters) but I am struggling with repeated characters such as "AA".

I have tried:

```
^(?=[AAB]{3}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$
^([AAB])(?!\1)([AAB])(?!\1|\2)([AAB])(?!\1|\2|\3)$
```

Do you have any ideas on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a feeling this may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Regex isn't really the best way to do something like this. Unless you want something as simple as `^(AAB|BAA|ABA)$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pattern that matches the three permutations:

```
^(?=.*B)(?=(.*A){2})...$
```

This pattern requires that:

- the length of the string is 3 (...)
- there is one `B` (the `(?=.*B)` lookahead)
- there are two `A`s (the `(?=(.*A){2})` lookahead)

But wouldn't the much simpler `^(AAB|ABA|BAA)$` also work?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yes, the `^(AAB|ABA|BAA)$` would have worked out for the simple example, but ultimately I want to generalize it for words with >3 characters. Now I am able to do so.

Comment: @d053420 Great! Glad I could help.